# eclipselink flush-mode COMMIT OUT of Memory

Tags: eclipselink, out-of-memory, flush

I'm using eclipselink JPA in my Java project

```
    <persistence-unit name="...." transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/tm-mapping.xml</mapping-file>
    <class>...</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="Oracle-JDBC" />
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements" value="true" />
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.native-sql" value="true" />
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.size.default" value="1000" />
        <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode" value="COMMIT" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

To encrease perfomance I use flush-mode commit. But when I give to script more data
I get Out of Memory and GC goes crazy.
As I see in heap dump the eclipse link cache for insert is too big, so maybe there is any parameter to flush inserts when cache is big.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a batch process that creates thousands of objects, you need to be sure you JVM has enough memory to hold all of them.  Each persist call requires the EntityManager to hold the entity until it is released.  This occurs when the EntityManager is closed, cleared or the entity evicted.

You can force the cache to be cleared using em.clear() at intervals, and call em.flush() just before that to ensure the changes are pushed to the database first.